# how to call REST API from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a url which gives json data...

I want to hit that URL from javascript but I am getting this error :

character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the file needs to be declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order mark as an encoding signature

Code :

```
function a(){
$.getJSON(url,function(data) { alert(data);});
}
```

full code :

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" ></meta>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

function a(){
$.getJSON(url,function(data) { alert(data);});
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text"/>
<input type="submit" value="search" onclick="a()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where does the error appear?

Comment: In this js : jquery-1.7.1.min.js

Comment: this is more of a problem with character encoding set by the document interpreting your request.  Who controls the server side code for this?

Comment: which URL do you want to load via AJAX?

Comment: @Brian Vanderbusch. Heroku

Comment: @ Zlatan
url=http://www.scalajobz.com/getAllJobs

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code seems correct.

Are you making a `fully qualified URL call`?

If you are making a fully qualified URL call, make sure of the following.

1. You are calling the same domain(same server). You can not make a
   simple JSON call to another domain.
2. If you want to use a cross domain call, you'll have to use JSONp

**Update:**
This is not working since it is a cross domain call.

Work around for this

**JavaScript**

Create a function

```
function getMyData(data) {
    alert(data);
    //Do the magic with your data
}
```

**Server side**

On server end wrap your data inside function syntax

```
getMyData("Enter your data here");
```

**JavaScript**

Then create a script tag and add a link to your cross-domain page

```
 <script type="text/javascript"
         src="cross ref url">
 </script>
```

For reference: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

EDIT: Another option is Create a proxy on your domain. ie create a page in your domain which internally calls the cross-domain page and return the same data to your Ajax call.

Comment: you mean I must use url as var url=url+"?callback=?"
I have used that..I didn't find any result....

Comment: No. Can you post the full vale of "url"

Comment: Simply use url = 'getAllJobs' and try

Comment: Are you calling it from the same domain (ie a page in scalajobz.com itself)?

Comment: Nothing happen...How can this url="getAllJobs" work without giving full URL..because I am using this URL in my another application...

Comment: No, I am not calling this from same domain...It is been calling from another application...

Comment: In that case you can not use simple JSON call. You need to go for JSONP