# POSTing JSON data to Server URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, post

I am facing problem when I am posting a JSON data to the server using Ajax call in jQuery the function does not enter success mode. When I post using the POSTER Plugin of Firefox it gets posted successfully. Sharing the code snippet and screenshot of the same:

```
function showSubscribeContent()
    {
        alert("*1*------- SUB CLICKED");

        var myJSONData = '{"data":{"mode" : "subscribe","technologyareas":[1],"assettypes":["podcast","documents"]}}';


        alert("*2*------- POSTING--------->"+myJSONData);


        $('#subscribePage').html('<h1>POSTING...</h1>');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'https://tt.s2.acc.com/tt/subscribe-service/uid=sagar_mate',
            data: myJSONData,
            dataType: 'application/xml',
            success: function(data) { 
             alert("*3*------- POSTED SUCCESSFULLY TO THE SERVER");

             $('#subscribePage').html('<h1>POSTED</h1>');

          } // Success Function 
          });   // Ajax Call
}
```

I am getting alert number *1* and *2* but not *3*.

Also when I post using POSTER plugin of Firefox, it gets posted easily.

[image]

The Response is success.

[image: POSTER Plugin Snaps]

I am unable to post the same data using AJAX call.

Thanks,
Ankit

Comment: Check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14433212/how-to-call-rest-api-from-javascript/14433462#comment20094520_14433462)

Comment: I am unable to understand the answer. Please help.

Comment: I got some part of it but there is something like serverside function.

Comment: Check this link [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

Comment: JSONP is for expecting data from another server. So how can it be useful for mobile application?

Comment: I mean, posting JSON data from mobile application to the server

Comment: Always add all these info in the question itself.. :) Check my answer. May help you

Comment: @Wolf Thanks. I am trying that. Can you please tell how this is possible: I can access XML of the same URL byt 'GET' method but cannot post JSON using 'POST' method. Is it possible? Is it something related to other domain URL?

Comment: @Wolf If its an other domain URL then I should not be able to access the XML data too. But I can access XML data hence the URL and my app are of same domain right?

Comment: Answered to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a header in beforeSend Function worked fine for me. Security reasons of CORS.

Answer (score 1):

Unless and until the URL in your AJAX call is of the same Domain, I don't think it will get posted successfully. POSTER plugin of Firefox doesn't put any such restriction on the domain, but browser will put this restriction on the application.

Try checking in the error: function(){alert(4);}

to see if it reaches the error handler atleast

Comment: both are of same domain. tt.stage2

Comment: @AnkitTanna So, your application is on same domain https://techtime.stage2.accenture.com

Comment: My application posts json data prepared from the application. But the application is not on the same domain. Application gets xml data from the domain.

Comment: I prepare a JSON string, and then want to post that JSON String to the server.

Comment: In that case, you will need to POST this JSON data to your own domain app first, which will simply POST the data on that techtime.stage2.accenture.com domain. You won't be able to POST data directly from browser on that URL since they are not on same App

Comment: but I have logged in with the credentials.

Comment: @AnkitTanna which credentials?

Comment: It reached error handler. But please tell me 1 thing, I can get xml data from these URLs but why cant I post the JSON data to the same URLs?

Comment: How are you fetching XML data from these URLs? Using AJAX get request in your javascript code?

Comment: it Reaches error handler. So you are telling that I cannot post it from a child browser used in application?

Comment: I want to try this comment of yours: In that case, you will need to POST this JSON data to your own domain app first, which will simply POST the data on that techtime.stage2.accenture.com domain. You won't be able to POST data directly from browser on that URL since they are not on same App

Comment: do you mean first save the JSON and then post the JSON?

Comment: I meant that first post this JSON to your own domain's server side code, and then send it to the other URL on the different app.

Answer (score 1):

Please clearify what you want, when using POSTER Plugin of Firefox you have specified datatype as json where as when using ajax you are using xml.

If you what to post data as JSON use JSON.stringify which accepts JSON object and convert it to string.

Comment: JSON.stringigy would in the end convert the data to this string right: var myJSONData = {"data":{"mode" : "subscribe","technologyareas":[1],"assettypes":["podcast","documents"]}};

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code

```
function showSubscribeContent()
    {
        alert("*1*------- SUB CLICKED");
        var myJSONData = {"data":{"mode" : "subscribe","technologyareas":[1],"assettypes":["podcast","documents"]}};
        alert("*2*------- POSTING--------->"+myJSONData);
        $('#subscribePage').html('<h1>POSTING...</h1>');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'https://tt.s2.acc.com/tt/subscribe-service/uid=sagar_mate',
            data: myJSONData,
            dataType: 'application/json',
            success: function(data) { 
             alert("*3*------- POSTED SUCCESSFULLY TO THE SERVER");
             $('#subscribePage').html('<h1>POSTED</h1>');

          } // Success Function 
          });   // Ajax Call
}
```

**Here I have changed the following lines**

Converted myJSONData to a JSON object from string

```
var myJSONData = {"data":{"mode" : "subscribe","technologyareas":[1],"assettypes":["podcast","documents"]}};
```

Note: try with the string(the way you were doing) if this is not working for you

Changed datatyle to JSON

```
dataType: 'application/json',
```

Comment: I am getting this error in console: In Failure{"readyState":4,"responseText":"","status":406,"statusText":"Not Acceptable"}

2013-01-22 17:41:49.595 TT[812:13403] [INFO] textStatus:error:Not Acceptable

Comment: I have tried what you had suggested. but it again and again goes in error function. "dataType" is for what type of data server would return. Its XML data that the server returns.

Comment: My mistake. :( So please use `contentType: 'application/json'`. And do you have any live sample of your code?

Comment: I am trying contentType: 'application/json' and dataType: 'xml'. Will check and let you know.